# Javascript code to verify an entry of a textbox

Tags: requiredfieldvalidator

Please I'm new to Javascript and i want add a JS code to check (using the "if" Selection structure) if the book code entered into the search box is valid (from a table data) and then proceed to the next page and if not, it should display invalid code..

I couldn't add the image of the output as I'm new here..

Please I'd appreciate the help.. Thanks in anticipation..

Comment: Please share what you have tried and add specific details with error (if any)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).